# sidebar icons are not clickable in lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

lazy loading sidebar is not working am using the mat-icons in that,am create the shared module in that am including the sidebar component
suppose icon is clicked.but its not navigate

side barcomponent.html

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/app/threats" routerLinkActive="active" matTooltip="Threats" matTooltipPosition="right" [matTooltipDisabled]="tolltip_disabled"
                    matTooltipClass="tooltip-bg">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="shield-half-full"></mat-icon>

                    <span class="tooltiptext">Threats</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: You are lazyLoading the module which contains sidebar Component or you are lazy loading the component with route 'app/threats' ???

Comment: create the one shared module in that i include the sidebar component

Comment: Okay, my question is , which module you are lazily loading? Is it this shared Module which you included sidebar component or the module which has component of 'app/threats'. Will be easy to help, if you can create example in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use routerLink="/app/threats" instead of href="/app/threats".

Comment: yes it's working but before am using routrLink="/app/threats",now am doing lazyloading in that not working

Comment: it's your lazy loading structure problem. show me your lazy loading